# How can I check if my model is valid from inside the razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to do a check if my model is valid from inside my Razor view. If it's valid then I want to be able to show some HTML.

How can I do this. I want something like

```
@if ( Model.IsValid ) {

}
```

but the above does not work

Comment: I hate asking this, but why? The only scenario I can think of is if you aren't allowed to use jQuery validation for some reason.

Comment: @Peter (and anyone else with the same question), imagine that you want to output a `div` element *but only if* previously submitted info is invalid, e.g. output a container element for an alert for invalid login credentials.

Comment: @Peter my dear friend, picture this: you are uploading a file and want to check if it has the correct format, can you do that on javascript? - no, you can't! So you can do a check on server side and if it fails, you can add an error to ModelState in order to display it on the page.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-check-if-model-is-valid-inside-the-razor-view-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can check whether or not the ModelState is valid, but keep in mind that you're only checking the validity of the ModelState at the time the web request was made:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
    ...
}
```

Additionally, you can check validatity of a property on the model in the view:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("FIELD_NAME")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning WHEN the model state is validated.

Comment: `FIELD_NAME` passed to `IsValidField` must be **full name** of the field in relation to the entire ViewModel hierarchy.