# ASP.Net MVC Razor engine: Make a javascript function aware if the user has input invalid data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view in which I want to generate a live graph using javascript based on a users input before he postes to the server, so that he can more clearly visualise the data he is inputing. However, I need to ignore any cells that contain invalid data.

I am looking for a check I can include in my javascript function that uses the existing ASP.Net MVC client side validation.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599639/how-can-i-check-if-my-model-is-valid-from-inside-the-razor-view) that:

```
if(!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {// Do something...
```

Should work but instead I get the following JS runtime error:

```
'ViewData' is undefined
```

Thanks in advance

Chopo

Comment: WARNING, This question was posted on the false premice that provided link is a similar question. I was compleatly barking up the wrong tree. As paciently explained by @karaxuna, `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` is C# Razor code and not a microsoft js library. The underlying question is still valid however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not check if form is valid or not before even loading the page (There is no C# scripts sent to client, it's executed on server side). So you should validate form on client side with javascript. For example with jquery validation it's done like this:

```
var form = $('form');
if(!form.valid()){
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: As I say, I get the following runtime error: 'ViewData' is undefined. The actual validation works and fields with invalid data appear in red

Comment: You should do it with javascript, not with C#. The validation you have written is useful when written in controller's action.

Comment: I have now added the `@` in front of the if statement (`@if`), but this now makes the entire function stop working and visual studio notifies me that ViewData is an _Expected Constant_

Comment: I am talking about talking about the c# controller that generates the view but of a javascript function in a js file called from within the page

Comment: I compleatly miss typed the previous reply, I ment to say i am NOT talking about C#, I clearly state in the question this is a Javascript question

Comment: @Chopo87 ViewData.ModelState.IsValid is not javascript property, it's C#. I wrote equivalent in javascript using jquery validation plugin

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks, that seems to work, I now realise the example I was working off was actualy an C# Razor view and not javascript, should I refrase the question, to avoid confusing future users?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing @ sign when using ViewData in javascript. Somthing like this:

```
if (@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid == false) {//Do something...
```

It might help.

Comment: ViewData.ModelState.IsValid == false is equivalent to !ViewData.ModelState.IsValid in C#

Comment: Thanks @Ali Shah Ahmed, unfortunately that did not solve the problem