# Editing input field when Html.ValidationMessageFor outputs error message

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco

I'm using C#/.NET in Visual Studio and the MVC framework.

I have a form that I'm working with, and I was able to get it to output the correct error message at the appropriate time. My issue is that the input field of the form is supposed to highlight red with a has-error class when the field is either not filled in or filled in incorrectly. I could do this if I was using regular form tags, but because this is connected to an Umbraco project, I have to use Html.EditorFor and Html.ValidationMessageFor.

Is there a way (either using jQuery or modifying the existing code) to add a class to the Html.EditorFor field upon Html.ValidationMessageFor deciding it should display the message?

Here is a portion of my View:

```
<div class="name-field">
    <label>Name</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "contact_name", @name = "contact_name", @placeholder = "Name" } })
    @if (@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) != null)
    {

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "contact-form-error-msg text-danger small-sized", @id = "contact-form-name-error-1", @style = "display:block;" })


    }
</div>
```

and here is the attribute in my Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a contact name.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Like I said, the error message shown in the model **is** showing up correctly. My issue is just applying the has-error class to the Html.EditorFor field which I have a feeling is going to require jQuery; however, I'm not sure how to access the existing code in a jQuery block.

Thank you.

Edit: I was notified that my question could be a possible duplicate of the question here ([How can I check if my model is valid from inside the razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599639/how-can-i-check-if-my-model-is-valid-from-inside-the-razor-view)). With some modification I was able to find the solution to my problem.

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("Name")) {
    <div class="name-field has-error">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "contact_name", @name = "contact_name", @placeholder = "Name" } })
        @if (@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) != null)
        {
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "contact-form-error-msg text-danger small-sized", @id = "contact-form-name-error-1", @style = "display:block;" })
        }
    </div>
} else {
    <div class="name-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "contact_name", @name = "contact_name", @placeholder = "Name" } })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599639

Comment: @AlexKrupka thank you for the flag. I checked it and it did help somewhat, but this is not a duplicate. You'll see in my edits why it doesn't really solve my problem the whole way :)

Comment: Ah my bad I apologize.

Comment: Upon further testing, I've realized that it is a duplicate of sorts. At least, I've found my answer using the code on the other question. Thank you so much for your help :)